# I have this snippet that I found in a old book of ML and I would like to ask if this function is correct

Tags: python, euclidean-distance

I got the book is 'Programming Collective Intelligence - Toby Segaran' when I was reading and checking some snippets from the book. It starts explain the euclidean distance:

```
from math import sqrt

sqrt(pow(5-4,2)+pow(4-1,2))
```

But it uses this to find the ED from :

```
critics={'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5,
 'Just My Luck': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5, 
 'The Night Listener': 3.0},
'Gene Seymour': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 
 'Just My Luck': 1.5, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0, 
 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5}, 
'Michael Phillips': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a Plane': 3.0,
 'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 4.0},
'Claudia Puig': {'Snakes on a Plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,
 'The Night Listener': 4.5, 'Superman Returns': 4.0, 
 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5}, 'Mick LaSalle': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,  'Just My Luck': 2.0, 'Superman Returns': 3.0, 'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.0}, 'Jack Matthews': {'Lady in the Water': 3.0, 'Snakes on a Plane': 4.0,  'The Night Listener': 3.0, 'Superman Returns': 5.0, 'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5}, 'Toby': {'Snakes on a Plane':4.5,'You, Me and Dupree':1.0,'Superman Returns':4.0}}

from math import sqrt

# Returns a distance-based similarity score for person1 and person2
def sim_distance(prefs,person1,person2):
  # Get the list of shared_items
  si={}
  for item in prefs[person1]: 
    if item in prefs[person2]: si[item]=1

  # if they have no ratings in common, return 0
  if len(si)==0: return 0

  # Add up the squares of all the differences
  sum_of_squares=sum([pow(prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2) 
                      for item in prefs[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
```

Using as:

```
import recommendation

recommendations.sim_distance(recommendations.critics, 'Lisa Rose','Gene seymour') # 0.148148148148
```

However, besides it imports sqrt from math, in the function it didn't use it right?
I was wondering if I am seeing wrong or the code is missing the sqrt in sum_of_squares?

Thank you

Paulo

Comment: You're right, the `sim_distance()` function is *not* using the `math.sqrt()` function. It's computing the sum of the _squares_ of the Euclidean distances. That value might be all that's really needed…however, if you really want the distance, I suggest you use `math.hypot()` which would be faster for this specific computation.

Comment: thanks bro. Stay safe. Paulo

Comment: This sim_distance function misses a return statement in the end